# Ignore Checks Based on Dependencies on Uchiwa using Sensu

Tags: monitoring, sensu, uchiwa

I'm currently using sensu and Uchiwa in an attempt to get rid of Zabbix, the problem is some checks persist even though they're dependent on other check.
For example:
I have a check that checks if the vpn process is active:

```
    "vpn-process": {
  "command": "check-process.rb -f /var/run/openvpn/client.pid",
  "subscribers": [
    "uni"
  ],
  "interval": 60,
  "dependencies": [
    "http-url1",
    "http-url2",
    "http-url3"
  ]
},
```

And I also have a check for http response, but this shouldn't work if the vpn is down.

```
    "http-url1": {
  "command": "python /etc/sensu/plugins/check-http.py https://url",
  "subscribers": [
    "uni" 
  ],
  "interval": 60
},
```

Still, Uchiwa warns about the VPN check **and** the HTTP checks.
[Uchiwa showing VPN and HTTP checks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hiI1.png)

I read about the [dependency check filters](https://github.com/sensu-extensions/sensu-extensions-check-dependencies), but as far as I could understand, it only works for handlers and Uchiwa is not a [handler](https://sensuapp.org/docs/0.24/reference/handlers.html#handler-types)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can't use Uchiwa as a handler (I checked with the maintainers), I had to write my own in python to call the API everytime the VPN is down and silence the checks I don't want to be shown in the dashboard. This way I created my own dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Uchiwa displays the current state of events in the system -- it is a passive view of checks/events, whereas handlers are active. The HTTP check will execute on-schedule even if VPN is down, and it will be considered `CRITICAL` regardless of whether you have a dependency filter.

The only way to have the HTTP check *not* result in a `CRITICAL` value if VPN is down is if you're somehow able to check for that case within the HTTP check and return a different value instead of `CRITICAL`. However, VPN being down might look very similar to other network-related issues, so it's probably best to avoid this scenario.

Maybe try making the VPN and HTTP checks into a [check aggregate](https://sensuapp.org/docs/1.1/reference/aggregates.html)?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, vase! Unlesse I got it wrong, the aggregate feature makes it possible to send one check to several clients and receive several results. In my case, I want to have checks that will only be performed if a first check is ok (sensu will only perform the http check if the vpn check is ok).